# Sort By Newest Products?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

How can I sort by Newest Products?

And is this Possible without an Extension and without me changing anything in the code, i.e. only with the standard Magento Settings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Making this change without altering the code is not feasible. You'll need to develop a plugin to achieve this, and you can follow the steps below to create the latest product plugin.

Create a **di.xml** file in **vendor/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Vendor_ModuleName_productoptions" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Config"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="catalog_productlist_products_data" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a **config.php** in **Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Model\Config.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Model;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Config
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        $customOption['newest_product'] = __('Newest Product');
        $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Create a **Toolbar.php** file in **Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as Productdata;

class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(Productdata $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
    {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        if ($currentOrder) {
            if ($currentOrder == "newest_product") {
                $direction = $subject->getCurrentDirection();
                $collection->getSelect()->order('created_at ' . $direction);
            }
            return $proceed($collection);
        }
    }
}
```